# Equations representation in state-space form

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, time-series

I have a set of equations which I have to represent in state-space form. Can someone please check if I’m doing it correctly

$
y_t= \tau_t\ + c_t,
$

$ 
\tau_t= g_t\ + \tau_{t-1}+v_t, 
$

$ 
g_t= g_{t-1}\ + w_t, 
$

$ 
c_t= \varphi_1c_{t-1}\ + \varphi_2c_{t-2}+e_t;
$

$
v_t,\ w_t,\ e_t -\ iid\ N(0,\ \ \sigma^2)
$

solution:

Unobserved states are $c_t, g_t, \tau_t$

$
\beta_t = \begin{bmatrix}\tau_t&g_t&c_t\\\end{bmatrix}'
$

then state equation:
$
\beta_t = \begin{bmatrix}\varphi_1&\varphi_2\\1&0\\\end{bmatrix}\beta_{t-1} + 
\begin{bmatrix}v_t\\0\\\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}\omega_t\\0\\\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}e_t\\0\\\end{bmatrix}
$

Observation equation:
$
x_t = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\\end{bmatrix}\beta_t
$

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Hi do you have harvey's text. https://www.amazon.com/Forecasting-Structural-Time-Harvey/dp/0521405734 The book has everything you ever wanted to know ( and probably didn't want to know ) about taking a time series specification and converting it to state space.

Comment: Nope, i don't have it, but thank you for the link

Comment: There is a problem with the dimensions in your state-space representation.

Comment: do you mean observation equation should be like [1 1]?